# How to fill a HTML table from a devise generated database table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise

very new to ruby on rails and devise.
I am currently trying to fill in a table on my HTML page that should list all records of my student table in my database(MYSQL).

```
<tbody>
<% for student in @students %>
 <tr>
  <td> <%= student.email %> </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

I have also tried `@students.each do |students|`.
both variants give the error NoMethodError, undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass
from what I put together from searching online, I'm referencing the students table without declaring it *somewhere*

```
def <name>
  @students = Students.all
end
```

from what i've seen, that needs to go somewhere but I can't figure out where.

Any suggestions on what to do would be great.

Rails 7.0.3
Devise 4.8

Answer (score 0):

You change `Students` to `Student` and use `each` loop

create: users_controller.rb

```
def index
 @students = Student.all
end
```

create a folder: views/users/index.html.erb

```
@students.each do |student|
// code
end
```

Comment: Which folder do I add the @students = Student.all ? devise made a students subfolder in the controllers folder but cant figure out where it might go, or just the application_controller.rb file since that seems to be the base one?
Again, very new to this stuff so i'm rather confused with where everything goes.

Comment: `def <name` in application_controller ? right

Comment: ok, got it working now. It failed when put in the application_controller.rb, so I put it in home_controller.rb since the page I was working on was in the home folder in views and it works. for future reference though if I delete the home folder and move everything into just the views folder id just put that @students = Student.all into the application_controller.rb?
Also thought that since application_controller seems to be the base controller and everything else inherits from it, putting it in there would be fine but i guess not.

Thanks for the help on this.

Comment: Okie @Rewi, goodluck